# how to play VIMEO video url in android videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview, vimeo-api

I have the VIMEO video url like "https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/119777338".
If am play this url in android videoview using following code

```
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri video = uri.parse("https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/119777338");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

I had error as "Can't play this video".
So how can i play this vimeo video url in android videoview.
Please kindly help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a **WebView** to play the video

Url would be something like:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/<VIDEO_ID_GOES_HERE>player_id=player&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1&api=1
```

Comment: Am tried that one also but same issue. Is there any library having to parse content of that url i used.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you have requested is a webpage, not a video. To turn vimeo.com urls into embed codes (for webviews) you should use oEmbed (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed).

If you are a PRO user you can get direct access to the video files through the api (https://developer.vimeo.com/api)